# Are right circular cylinders prismatic?

Tags: geometry

In a website it was explained that a prism has polygon bases and all sides are perpendicular to the bases.A polygon with a large number of sides can be approximated to a circle.But it was not concluded whether a cylinder is prismatic.

Comment: Cylinder isn't a prism because it has curved sides.

Comment: Polygons may *approximate* a circle, yet a circle is not a polygon. Likewise, prisms may *approximate* a cylinder, yet a cylinder is not a prism. Further, pyramids may *approximate* a cone, yet a pyramid is not a cone. That said, "cylinder" is sometimes defined more generically as a figure with an arbitrary planar region (circle, polygon, parabola, what-have-you) as its base; likewise, for a "cone". But the terms "prism" and "pyramid" are typically reserved for the flat-edged figures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your definition of "prism". A prism usually starts with some base polytope and errects then a cartesian product with a finite line segment. Thus when loosing the polytopal base to any solid base, you well can consider a cylinder as the prism product of a disc and a finite line segment.

Alternatively you can consider the circular disc as an infinite limit of regular polygons with increasing number of sides. And then for each finite approximant you clearly will have a prism. Thus it seems fair to call the limit, the cylinder, then too as the limiting case of a prism as well.

--- rk